# Using ironpython in Visual studio code

Tags: 16.04, python, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner to programming, I need to use ironpython to execute my code.

What I did till now is I wrote my complete code in python and executed it with zero errors.

Now I wish to change my python path to ironpython in visual studio code, which I did as below:

[image: changed python path to ironpython]

And now I have the following error:

[image: Error]

I am looking for solutions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide you .json file content as well, or the equivalent?

Comment: hi @avazula  i am using a csv file as input it has large amount of data

Comment: When I said .json file content I meant your configuration file. .json is the vscode format for many languages like c++ & MySQL, I don't know about python though. Can you identify such a file in your project?

Comment: i am sorry my knowledge in python is also very limited, i couldnt find any such file, but i think the problem may be that ironpython cant use csv library of normal python. and i dont know how to invoke that using visual code studio.

Comment: Don't worry, I'll open vscode here and get familiar with python features so I'll see if I can help you :)

Comment: What's your ironpython version? I'm sorry, I don't know this framework but I looked on Google and I found [this](https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/csv.html) which says csv is supported by ironpython version 2.3+ only. This might be your problem?

Comment: Also, if you haven't seen it yet, I've found [this tutorial](https://github.com/gtalarico/ironpython-stubs/wiki/Visual-Studio-Code) which could help you configure your program if the csv thing is not the problem indeed.

Comment: The picture of your text is hard to read.  It'd be substantially easier to deal with if you would replace the image with actual text from your screen.  It'd also make it easier to copy and search your error messages through Google.  The system would even help you by matching related Q&A's with text from your question if it were actual text instead of a picture of your text.